# Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, error, spfx-webparts

Inside our SPFx web part we are getting this error:

[image]

So inside the SPFx directory, I ran these 2 commands:

```
npm install react

npm install --save-dev @types/react
```

But we are still getting the same error. Any advice?

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? If you are using SPFx 1.14, make sure to use TypeScript v3.9. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes i am using SPFx 1.14.. so how i can install the specific TS  version ?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.eliostruyf.com/define-the-typescript-version-you-want-to-use-in-sharepoint-framework/) and [this](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/use-different-typescript-versions-in-sharepoint-framework-projects/).

Comment: @GaneshSanap so i will need to run this `npm i @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9`?

Comment: yes, correct. Use `npm i @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9`.

Comment: @GaneshSanap ok run the command but still i am getting the same errors